# Tree View with AngularJS and Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying out to write code for web application. I've set of path in list variable,

```
a = {"c:\windows\1.html","c:\Program Files\le.txt","c:\Program Files\file\File.txt"}
```

How can display this variable in Web Page in tree view, were clicking root folder ie., 'C' should display all the other sub-folders, and if folder is selected it should display files and its sub-folder only "C:\Windows"

If you're providing sample codes, it will be great help to get started.